# CW complex structure on manifolds with certain dimensional cells

Tags: smooth-manifolds, cw-complexes, morse-theory

I started reading Morse theory and I learnt one of the fundamental theorem which says that any smooth closed manifold admits a CW complex structure. I had a following question: Given a smooth, closed manifold M, how can we say that in any CW complex structure structure on M, certain dimensional cells must exists?
For example, in orientable surfaces with genus greater than 1 we can say that the 1 cells must exist using Euler characteristic argument. What can we say in general?

Comment: The no of $k$ cells is $\ge H_k (M, \mathbb Z)$. Not sure if one can say more.

Comment: Oh. I got the point. We can use cellular homology to conclude this.